# Automating browser actions using AI

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, deep-learning, convolutional-neural-networks, ai-design

I am at a very initial stage of my research so I will try to describe what I am trying to achieve:

I want to create an AI model which learns how to navigate the browser's component like clicking or creating new favorites and tabs, or navigating browser action menu, or bookmarking the website etc. In short, automating the testing for browser using selenium and an AI model so that over time the model learns itself to navigate the browser and test different functionality itself and eventually it test the functionalities that are not seen by the model before. For example: if I feed the AI model how browser is closed when "x" is clicked and minimize when "-" is clicked, next it can learn itself how to maximize the browser.

The initial input could be to record some videos of navigating the browser using selenium and then feed it to the model and with time it learns itself to go to different section of the browser which the model does not know and still test it.

Is it even possible to combine AI and selenium together to create something like this? If yes, how can I achieve it and what is the best approach to develop such model.

Thanks in advance.